# Windows 7. enable write caching setting is reset

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

Enabling write caching policy on external hard drive causes serious troubles for me. [More details here](https://superuser.com/questions/629612/vmware-workstation-takes-too-much-time-to-shut-down). But after disabling this setting it always gets reset after getting back from sleep mode. Though it's not reset after restart.

Is there a way to really save this setting on external hard drive **or entirely disable this feature for OS**?

Comment: Not really. So far I have not seen any consumer SATA/USB drive that saves write cache policy. It's pretty much necessary for the OS to reinforce among power cycles. Same issue exists on Linux as well but there are quite handy ways to implement workaround for it (e.g. resume.target of systemd). One workaround I can think of is to stop the BIOS/UEFI powering off the USB ports when sleep, but that really depends on whether it provides such an option in its setting.